# android: Retaining image position or arrangement even the app is closed

Tags: android, database

I want to make a seatplan application that retains the students' choice of seat even the application is closed.

Flow is like this, for the first run, I want to assign a certain student to the first seat. I want to retain the student's position even the app is closed so that next time that I will open the app, I can see that the student is occupying the first seat.

Also, I want to make multiple seatplans for multiple subjects.

Any help or ideas will be very much appreciated. I'm respectfully asking for your help. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this matter You have to use SharedPreferences,using this example :

**Store Data**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Some Name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve Data**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
    String name = prefs.getString("key", "return this string if key not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ziem and Boukharist. :) One question, can i make multiple sharedpreferences files?

Comment: change the name of "MY_PREFS_NAME"

Comment: Take a look here for futher information: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much guys